# Android and ios folders missing in react native app

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I created a react native app using `expo init` and I choose the `blank (Typescript)` template. Now I want to extract an apk but in the documentation, there is something to configure which is in the `android` folder, but I don't have it. I tried to find something but nothing worked. I run: `react-native upgrade` , `react-native link` , `react-native run-android`(Android project not found. Are you sure this...).

Is there a solution to generate those folders? And if I create an app with `minimal (Typescript)` template, the folders are there but it's also native android(java) and ios projects, and I want to know why.

I have `react: 16.13.1` and `react-native: 0.63.2`.

I know that I could re-create the app with minimal template, but I don't want to add these folders to git.

Comment: Run expo eject command from your project directory, this will eject the project from expo and create those directory. If you dont want to push those folders to git then you can add them in .gitignore.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. And what are these folders for?